# Is there an easy way to make these surfaces flat

Tags: modeling

[image]

[image]

How can i flatten those surfaces so that they are just a bunch of cuboids? I tried rotating but it doesn't work.

Comment: S + Z + 0 should do it

Comment: Ah thank you it worked